# SQL query to bring back all orders only if all order details are in a list

Tags: sql-server

I have an `orders` table that contains a lot of `order` specific info that is irrelevant to the question. However, I then have an `orderDetails` table that has a `foreign key` `(orders.id == orderDetails.orderId)`. In this `orderDetails`, a customer can select to order lots of flavors of a product, each flavor gets a new entry in this table linked back to the main `order`.

What I want to do is select all the `orders` where ALL the flavors are present in the `order`. So, if an `order` has apple, peach and orange and I query for apple and peach, it wouldn't return that order because orange wasn't in my query.

I have tried `subqueries` and so on, but I feel like the only way to solve it is with looping each order and looking at the details, but that is horribly inefficient. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders
WHERE id IN (SELECT orderId 
         FROM orderdetails 
         WHERE  flavor IN('apple', 'peach', 'orange')) 
AND isInvoiced = 1 
AND isShipped  = 0 
AND isOnHold   = 0
```

So, if I don't have any peach in stock, I want to see `orders` that do not contain any peach:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE id IN (SELECT orderId
         FROM orderdetails 
         WHERE flavor IN ('apple', 'orange')) 
AND isInvoiced = 1 
AND isShipped  = 0 
AND isOnHold   = 0
```

The problem with the existing query here is that it returns everything because it just says, sure, you asked for apple... sure you asked for orange and this `order` contains those so I will return it. I need it to be ALL or nothing.

In the real database, the flavors are ID's, I just simplified it for this example.

Database tables were requested... I'll go ahead and list them as they really exist.

```
orders
-------
id
isInvoiced
isShipped
isOnHold

orderDetails
------------
id
orderId
flavorId
```

One more edit, this is my original failed attempt:

```
select * from orders WHERE id in
(
    select orderId from orderdetails where flavorId in
    (
        '616a6d8e-be2e-4740-820b-1cad2a3d89b5',
        '5d02f25b-f717-4079-97af-8aa444fe26b1',
        '3504be8b-bebe-4b69-a22f-724d90003f99',
        'c0a5a036-6dbe-417d-afcf-644f5520f2a8',
        '29bfdea5-f270-44f0-9f48-245992af8401',
        '29e53a21-4fdc-40e7-8bd9-733058a48097',
        '60a90505-b9f5-4a60-8444-a35c2477d4a5',
        'c9b93e89-98b0-4765-aedf-3a5f9d182c77',
        '651ea709-a885-4f12-ad53-3290e8f0b18f',
        'c5962375-d4d5-4ec7-82c0-0293475e6204',
        '7faeffc0-fa88-4904-a6a9-7201949b23fd',
        '24979b0d-7200-4a7d-9271-d26912d1b16d',
        '5efeb81a-7642-4484-b8fc-62544bc8bff7'
    )
)
and isInvoiced = 1 and isShipped = 0 and isOnHold = 0
```

That list of ID's would change based on what flavors are actually in stock.

Comment: You should share the table structures as well

Comment: I realize now I left out one very important part in that each order may have 1 or any number of flavors, not all have to be present. So, I don’t believe any of the count options below will work.

Comment: To help with understanding, this is an inventory system. If we are out of a flavor, we want to filter those orders out of the screen so we can focus on just the orders that we have flavors in stock for. So, I want to be able to pass a list of flavors that are in stock and only return orders that match.

Comment: @Alan. You want to be able to pass a list of flavors that are in stock and only return orders that match those flavors. So if you have only apple and orange (and peach is out of stock) in your stock and one order has apple , orange (which are in stock) and peach (which is out of stock) do you want to return that order too?

Comment: I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: That is fantastic advice and I wish I would have explained it more thoroughly the first time. However, short of deleting this and reposting, I admitted my mistake and asked for further help!

Answer (score 0):

basically you can just `GROUP BY flavor` with condition `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`. So orders with those 3 flavor will be listed

```
select * 
from   orders o
where  exists
       (
           select x.flavor
           from   orderdetails x
           where  x.orderId = o.id
           and    x.flavor in ('apple', 'peach', 'orange')
           group by x.flavor
           having count(*) = 3
       ) 
and    isInvoiced = 1 
and    isShipped  = 0 
and    isOnHold   = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use count function to make sure all flavors are represented.

```
select o.* 
from   orders o
inner join 
       (
           select orderId, count(*) as flavorCount
           from   orderdetails 
           where  flavor in ('apple', 'peach', 'orange')
           group by orderId
       ) as t1

on o.orderId = t1.orderId

and    isInvoiced = 1 
and    isShipped  = 0 
and    isOnHold   = 0
and     t1.falvourCount = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question completely changed via this comment "*I realize now I left out one very important part in that each order may have 1 or any number of flavors, not all have to be present.*"

---

The following query meets **the original requirements**: "*What I want to do is select all the orders where ALL the flavors are present in the order*" & "*I need it to be ALL or nothing.*"

An order might have more than one item referring to a flavor ("apple pie", and "apple cake" for example), so I recommend you use 3 case expressions in a having clause to guard against this, whilst still achieving your objective:

```
select o.* 
from   orders as o
inner join (
           select orderId 
           from   orderdetails 
           group by orderId
           having sum(case when flavor = 'apple' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
           and sum(case when flavor = 'peach' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
           and sum(case when flavor = 'orange' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
       ) as od on o.id = od.orderid
where o.isInvoiced = 1 
and o.isShipped  = 0 
and o.isOnHold   = 0
```

Note that the use of an `inner join` limits the orders listed to only those that refer to all 3 flavors.

This query is demonstrated here: http://rextester.com/AKMM54555

Comment: I’m working through this solution to see if I can make it work, but I’m struggling to get it to return any results. I’ll keep at it and post back with code if I can’t get it.

Comment: After reading your example some more, I’m not sure it fits my last comment of being able to support when one order might have just Apple. Another order might have Apple and peach, etc. all are valid. I want to avoid returning an order if it contains a certain flavor, but if it doesn’t have it, I want to return it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if you have a list of out-of-stock and in-stock flavors. 
So if for example 'peach' is out of stock , and 'apple' and 'orange' are in stock, the following query will produce Orders that have only 'apple' OR 'orange' :

```
   SELECT * FROM orders 
   WHERE
     id IN (SELECT id FROM orderdetails WHERE  flavor IN ('apple','orange')  ) -- in stock
   AND 
     id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM orderdetails WHERE  flavor   IN ('peach')  )  --out of stock
```

What do you think ?